# What do I need to do to run spatialite in a webrole on Azure?

Tags: azure, spatialite

I've been looking into using spatialite on Azure.  The precompiled binaries at [SpatiaLite 2.3.1](http://www.gaia-gis.it/spatialite/binaries.html) are all for x86 and trying to include libspatialite-1.dll of course won't work since Azure requires x64.

Am I just missing something simple, or do I need to try to compile the binaries into a x64 dll?  Is that a path I should go down?

Any guidance or link to a tutorial to get SpatiaLite running in Azure would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding of Azure, you will need to recompile the SpatiaLite assemblies into a x64/AnyCPU dll. Also if the SpatiaLite assemblies make reference to any x32 assemblies, these too will need to be recompiled in order to get it working in Azure.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/haniatassi/archive/2009/03/20/using-a-32bit-dll-in-the-windows-azure.aspx

There are alternatives to recompiling your assemblies, but its quite complex.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowsazuredevelopment/thread/43721d3c-f6e5-4f72-8c62-39904156c042

Comment: It's been a while since I tried to go down this path.  I never did get it to work.  I agree that in general, the answer is correct in that is what is required.  In specifics there are a LOT of blanks to fill in.  Was really hoping someone that has done it would be more explicit in what is needed.